# How to set input value to 1 if empty when clicked

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working with WooCommerce in WordPress I wanted to add my own buttons to increment or decrement the quantity value. I found some code that helped me do this, but I've noticed that if the quantity value is equal to nothing that I cant increment it back to one using my own buttons it just stays empty, but the default buttons increment it back to one.

How can I check if the value equals nothing and set it to one? I tried to do it myself with an if statement but it didn't work.

```js
jQuery('.plus').on('click',function(e){
        var val = parseInt($(this).prev('input').val());
        jQuery(this).prev('input').val( val+1 );

        if( jQuery(isNaN(val)) ){
            jQuery(this).val() = 1;
        }
    });

    jQuery('.minus').on('click',function(e){
        var val = parseInt($(this).next('input').val());
        if(val !== 0){
            jQuery(this).next('input').val( val-1 );
        } 
    });
```

```html
<div class="quantity">
  <input class="minus" type="button" value="-">
  <input type="number" class="input-text qty text" step="<?php echo esc_attr( $step ); ?>" min="<?php echo esc_attr( $min_value ); ?>" max="<?php echo esc_attr( 0 < $max_value ? $max_value : '' ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_name ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_value ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) ?>" size="4" pattern="<?php echo esc_attr( $pattern ); ?>" inputmode="<?php echo esc_attr( $inputmode ); ?>" />
  <input class="plus" type="button" value="+">
</div>
```

Comment: Syntax error here: `jQuery(this).val() = 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are giving an assignment to the `val` function instead you need to pass the value in `()` It accepts the value as a parameter. Another thing is you are trying to update the value of the `+` button instead you need to update the value of `input` field by using `jQuery(this).prev('input').val(1);` like this

```js
jQuery('.plus').on('click', function(e) {
  var val = parseInt($(this).prev('input').val());
  jQuery(this).prev('input').val(val + 1);

  if (isNaN(val)) {
    jQuery(this).prev('input').val(1);
  }
});

jQuery('.minus').on('click', function(e) {
  var val = parseInt($(this).next('input').val());
  if (val !== 0) {
    jQuery(this).next('input').val(val - 1);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity">
  <input class="minus" type="button" value="-">
  <input type="number" class="input-text qty text" step="<?php echo esc_attr( $step ); ?>" min="<?php echo esc_attr( $min_value ); ?>" max="<?php echo esc_attr( 0 < $max_value ? $max_value : '' ); ?>" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_name ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_value ); ?>"
    title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) ?>" size="4" pattern="<?php echo esc_attr( $pattern ); ?>" inputmode="<?php echo esc_attr( $inputmode ); ?>" />
  <input class="plus" type="button" value="+">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would instead fix the input generation maybe using an in-line ternary operator.

You are actually generating the input's value using the following:

```
value="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_value ); ?>"
```

By checking the value you could always insert a valid number, preventing invalid value by using

```
value="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_value >= 0 ? $input_value : 0 ); ?>"
```

However, if you need to keep empty values just rely on Sanchit Patiyal's answer